# Best way to remove trailing slashes in URLs with PHP

Tags: php

I have some URLs, like `www.amazon.com/`, `www.digg.com` or `www.microsoft.com/` and I want to remove the trailing slash, if it exists, so not just the last character. Is there a `trim` or `rtrim` for this?

Answer (score 294):

You put `rtrim` in your question, why not just look it up?

```
$url = rtrim($url,"/");
```

As a side note, look up any PHP function by doing the following:

- http://php.net/functionname
- http://php.net/rtrim
- http://php.net/trim

(`rtrim` stands for 'Right trim')

Answer (score 13):

Simple and works across both Windows and Unix:

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/\\')
```

Comment: why the `/\\ ` instead of `/`?

Comment: @SethB The second parameter is a list of strings to trim. One character is "/", and another is "\". However, in PHP strings, you need to escape forward slashes, which looks like "\\". Therefore: "/\\" or "\\/" would work.

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for a way to remove trailing slash and redirect the browser, I have come up with an answer that I would like to share for anyone coming after me:

```
//remove trailing slash from uri
if( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/") and preg_match('{/$}',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
    header ('Location: '.preg_replace('{/$}', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();
}
```

The `($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/")` will avoid host URI e.g www.amazon.com/ because [web browsers always send a trailing slash after a domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581411/do-web-browsers-always-send-a-trailing-slash-after-a-domain-name), and `preg_match('{/$}',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` will match all other URI with trailing slash as last character. Then `preg_replace('{/$}', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` will remove the slash and hand over to `header()` to redirect. The `exit()` function is important  to stop any further code execution.

Comment: Yes good way for clean the extra Backslash "/" from URL but when i that put extra Backslash in front of url,it is crashing

Answer (score -20):

```
$urls="www.amazon.com/ www.digg.com/ www.microsoft.com/";
echo preg_replace("/\b\//","",$urls);
```

Comment: No, don't use regex for this.

Comment: Besides, the RE would fail pretty nicely for URLs that also contain slashes in the middle.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. It simply assumes the URLs are concatenated in a string, as opposed to an array. If they're in an array, Erik's answer is better. If they are in a string separated by spaces or line breaks, this is fine.

Comment: @supertrue There is nothing wrong with this answer _except_ the fact, that RE is _awfully slow_ in compare to other string-related functions in PHP! Even PHP.net docs warns, that regular expressions functions should be avoided in favor of simple string-related functions, due to speed and performance issues.