# Do web browsers always send a trailing slash after a domain name?

Tags: http, browser

Is there consistency and/or a standard on how browsers send an URL to a host related to trailing slashes?

Meaning, if I type in `http://example.com` in the address bar of a web browser, is the browser suppose to add a trailing slash (`http://example.com/`) or not?

Answer (score 34):

The HTTP request sent from the browser to the server does not include the domain name, only the "path" portion (starting from the first slash after the domain name). Since the path cannot be empty, a `/` is sent in that case.

A sample GET request for the root of a web site might be:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

The `/` above cannot be omitted.

Comment: To clarify this, domain is sent in `Host` header (HTTP 1.1 only).

Comment: So what you're saying is that even if you have an empty path, the URL is guaranteed to have a trailing slash?

Comment: @Hank: What I'm saying is that *if* you have an empty path, a single `/` is sent. This doesn't say anything about trailing slashes if the path portion is *not* empty (in that case, the browser sends exactly what is on the URL bar, but the server may choose to redirect the browser in its response).

Comment: (Sorry for intervention.) In other words: if the path is empty, browser adds /. If path is not empty, the trailing / is added by server (if added at all).

Comment: @jholster Wrong. See RFC 2616. A quote is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581514/529442

Comment: Note that non-browser HTTP clients such as **curl** does not automatically add a trailing slash to domain-only URLs, unlike web browsers.

Answer (score 18):

As RFC 2616 tells:

> 3.2.2 http URL
>
> The "http" scheme is used to locate
>   network resources via the HTTP
>   protocol. This section defines the
>   scheme-specific syntax and
>   semantics for http URLs.
>
> http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":"
>   port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
>
> If the port is empty or not given,
>   port 80 is assumed. The semantics
>   are that the identified resource is
>   located at the server listening    for
>   TCP connections on that port of that
>   host, and the Request-URI    for the
>   resource is abs_path (section 5.1.2).
>   The use of IP addresses    in URLs
>   SHOULD be avoided whenever possible
>   (see RFC 1900 [24]). **If    the
>   abs_path is not present in the URL, it
>   MUST be given as "/" when    used as a
>   Request-URI for a resource** (section
>   5.1.2). If a proxy    receives a host name which is not a fully qualified
>   domain name, it    MAY add its domain
>   to the host name it received. If a
>   proxy receives    a fully qualified
>   domain name, the proxy MUST NOT change
>   the host    name.

Read more: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html#ixzz0kGbpjYWa

> 5.1.2 Request-URI
>   ...
>   For example, a client wishing    to retrieve the
>   resource above directly from the
>   origin server would    create a TCP
>   connection to port 80 of the host
>   "www.w3.org" and send    the lines:
>
> ```
>    GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
>    Host: www.w3.org
> ```
>
> followed by the remainder of the
>   Request. **Note that the absolute path
>   cannot be empty; if none is present in
>   the original URI, it MUST be    given
>   as "/" (the server root).**

Read more: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html#ixzz0kGcaRbqU

Answer (score 10):

Note that it's a [very different](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/001327.html) matter when the URL has a path element:

```
http://example.com/dir
```

is a *different URL* than

```
http://example.com/dir/
```

and could in fact contain different content, and have a different search engine ranking.

Comment: this is a good point. It's recommended to end the url with "/"

Comment: @Claudio, some reference please?

Comment: @Yaggo: take a look on google "trailing slash url". I don't remember a single place where I've read it, sorry man.

Comment: I did and found no evidence, only personal opinions. URIs without trailing slash are extremely popular (which alone doesn't quarantee anything) and I have never seen fact-based arguments against them. (Back when the web was mainly static files, appending / to directories was maybe de-facto standard, but I don't see a reason to prefer that nowdays.)

Comment: well, a url without "/" could be a file or a directory so the web server must do an extra check. If I'm not wrong some web server could by default do a redirect from www.whatever.com/dir to www.whatever.com/dir/. If I have to select an approach, trailing backslash would be the safer I think

Comment: The concept of 'directory' is vague in today's web. Leaving out trailing slash doesn't force server make "extra check" _per se_. URIs don't necessarily reflect a file hierarchy or have anything to do with files. I think your point of view is about statistic files, while I'm talking about web applications generally.

Comment: Yes, for rewritten URLs urls probably it's only question of prefference. I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the protocol is concerned, `http://example.com/something` and `http://example.com/something/` are quite different. Some servers might redirect you from one to the other if it is implemented in such a way.

As for the pure domain names, it always sends a request ending with a slash.
(The domain name itself is not included in the path section of an HTTP request, just as Greg Hewgill and the others wrote. It is, however, included in the headers.)

You can check it with a tool like Fiddler or WireShark.

Comment: This is incorrect. `/something/` is different from `/something` in an HTTP sense. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html