# Adding of trailing slash with urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581411/do-web-browsers-always-send-a-trailing-slash-after-a-domain-name).

It seems urllib2.build_opener does not add the document path (`/`) if the url contains just the domain name.  For example a web request to http://ibm.com would result in:

```
GET http://ibm.com HTTP/1.1
```

instead of:

```
GET http://ibm.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

or:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: ibm.com
```

as practiced by other Http clients such as web browsers or .NET's HttpWebRequest.

Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Have you encountered any web server which doesn't serve the desired page in such a case?

Comment: The web servers I tried don't mind the missing '/`, but when I go through Fiddler, it flags it as a protocol violation and refuses to continue.