# ngRoute adds trailing slash to some url but not all

Tags: angularjs

When user go to either  `localhost:8888` or `localhost:8888/`, my angular application change to url to `http://localhost:8888/#!/`

This is my angular app in home page:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: ((window.status === 'signup') ? '/signup' : '/signin')
            })
            .when("/signin", {
                templateUrl: "/public/user/signin.html",
                controller: "signinController"
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                templateUrl: "/public/user/signup.html",
                controller: "signupController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
])
```

if user go to `http://localhost:8888/auth`, angular redirects to `http://localhost:8888/auth#!/signin`,

only if user go to `http://localhost:8888/auth/`, angular redirects to `http://localhost:8888/auth/#!/signin`

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: ((window.status === 'signup') ? '/signup' : '/signin')
            })
            .when("/signin", {
                templateUrl: "/public/user/signin.html",
                controller: "signinController"
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                templateUrl: "/public/user/signup.html",
                controller: "signupController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
])
```

the angular official website and most of the books recommend using `xxx/#!/xxx` format. How can I do that?

Edit: I understand that I can add the trailing slash from the server side. but user can directly type `xxx.com/auth`. 
Why is `xxx.com` working but not `xxx.com/auth`?

Edit2: the tutorial sample project works for all urls. we have pretty much the same implementation

`http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/#/phones`

try to enter `http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app` (without the trailing slash

Tutorial link: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should fix on your back-end by adding a 301 redirect from `/auth` to `/auth/`.

Nginx:

```
rewrite ^/auth$ /auth/ permanent;
```

Apache:

```
Redirect "/auth" "/auth/" [R=301]
```

Comment: can i fix it with angular code? because user are most likely to type `www.xxx.com/auth`

Comment: You can also redirect using JavaScript using `if (location.pathname === '/auth') { location.replace('/auth/'); }` , but it's better to fix this on your server because that will be faster.

Comment: you mean $location.replace? or $window.location.replace()

Comment: `$window.location.replace`. But again, doing this on your server will be faster. The delay of a javascript redirect will be noticable by the user.

Comment: why is the `localhost:8888` working but not `localhost:8888/auth`?

Comment: I dont think i can put it in `app.config(['$locationProvider'...)`. so do i put it in every controller?

Comment: I would put it outside the AngularJS system because then it will be faster, like my first comment to this answer, for example in the same file where you define your main module. Otherwise it will wait until AngularJS initializes before it executes the redirect, which will be more delay. `localhost:8888` is the same as `localhost:8888/`. Some browsers hide the trailing slash when there's no pathname or hash, but the first slash is always there. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2581411/451480

Comment: I dont understand the posted question. they are saying xxx.com/auth and xxx.com/auth/ are different. but they are the same in my angular app

Comment: if `localhost:8888/auth` is not working, you should serve the same HTML file  there on your server, or link to `http://localhost:8888/#!/auth/signin` instead.

Comment: I just checked the tutorial sample project. the backslash is added in all urls. please refer to my edited question