# Removing trailing forward slash from PHP redirect header location

Tags: php, redirect

I have the following script:

```
function redirect_to($location) {
    header("Status: 301");
    header("Location: $location");
    exit;
}

if($_GET['check'] === '1') {
    redirect_to('http://www.domain.com?aaa=bbb');
}
```

For some reason, it's adding a forward slash to the tail end of the domain name. I also tried echoing a JavaScript `windows.location`, same problem.

```
http://www.domain.com/?aaa=bbb
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This is Browser behavior... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581411/do-web-browsers-always-send-a-trailing-slash-after-a-domain-name

Comment: You can't: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Comment: Why is it a problem for you?

Comment: becouse the analytics is not tracking correctly. i suspect its due to the url being altered. im redirecting requests to an affiliate network "viglink" and they are not registering the requests.

Comment: Are you using one of their monetization API's? Like *monetized URLs* or *monetized links*?

Comment: yes. the API  formats links into affiliate links. it needs to look like this [http://redirect.viglink.com?key=[API]&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com] but the  added **/** after viglink.com  seems to break the syntex required