# trim slashes from Request_Uri

Tags: php, url, uri, trim

here's my code snippet to start with:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // gives /test/test/ from http://example.org/test/test/
echo"$url"; 
trim ( $url ,'/' );
echo"$url";
```

I use this in combination with .htaccess rewrite, I’ll get the information from the URL and generate the page for the user with PHP using `explode`.
I don't want .htaccess to interpret the URL, which is probably better, but I am more common with PHP and I think it’s more flexible.

I already read this (which basically is what I want):
[Best way to remove trailing slashes in URLs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392677/best-way-to-remove-trailing-slashes-in-urls-with-php)

The only problem is, that `trim` doesn’t trim the leading slashes. Why?
But actually it should work. Replacing `'/'` with `"/"`, `'\47'` or `'\x2F'` doesn’t change anything.
It neither works online nor on localhost.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `trim` function *returns* the trimmed string. It doesn't modify the original. Your third line should be:

```
$url = trim($url, '/');
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in one line...

```
echo trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
$url = trim($url, '/');
```

You also should just do

```
echo $url;
```

It is faster.

Answer (score 1):

`trim` does not modify the original. You'll need to do something such as:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // gives /test/test/ from http://example.org/test/test/
echo"$url"; 
$url = trim ( $url ,'/' );
echo"$url";
```